# SSRS: Use SQL Query in the place of a parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2012

I am trying to create an SSRS subscription.  And for my StartDate and EndDate time parameters, I would like to have "Start from the Sunday before last, and continue to last Saturday evening" i.e today is 01/04/2017 so StartDate = '2017-12-24 00:00:00.000' and the EndDate = '2017-12-30 23:59:59.997'.

These dates are the product of the following statements.

```
DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, -1,GetDate()), -8)

DateAdd(ms, 86399997, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, -1,GetDate()), -2))
```

However, whenever I try to drop these strings into the Subscription maker UI, it just batts it away and puts a date into the field.

[image]

Does anyone know how to put an evaluatable query into parameter fields?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I would recommend using a data-driven subscription. You can write the expression in SQL and then pass that value to the parameter.

Comment: @StevenWhite this is through the SSRS interface for folks who aren’t too technical.

Comment: If this UI doesn't allow data-driven subscriptions, the only way to use any calculation would be to have it built into the report.